# Extending the string class - Inheritance - error C2835 ( user defined conversion takes no formal parameters )

Tags: c++

As an exercise I am trying to extend the string class adding more functions. I am still studying C++ so do not touch my reputation just for fun ! This is a difficult exercise for me. 
This code works perfectly until main reaches string profumo=prova.replace("y","b") ( signalled by //***** ) where I cannot make it printed by cout because

> error C2835: user-defined conversion 'superString::operator std::string' takes no formal parameters

The normal converter I used before does not work in this case, the new that I addad ( signalled by //***** ) does not work either.
Also, if anyone has comments about other parts of the code, he is welcome to post them.
Thanks in advance.

```
// superString.cpp : in questa versione vogliamo creare superString come 
// inheritance della classe string e poi aggiungiamo le funzioni che vogliamo
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class superString : public string
{
private:
    string m_frase;
public:
    superString(string frase){ m_frase=frase; }
    operator string() { return m_frase; }
    operator string(string, string) { return m_frase; }    // *****
    int length() {return static_cast<int>(m_frase.length());}
    string chr(int posizione)
    {
            if (posizione < static_cast<int>(m_frase.length()))
            {
                     string result(m_frase,posizione,1);
                     return result;
            }
            else return "xx";
    }
    string read(){ return m_frase;}
    void replace_chr(string a, string b)
    {
            string *cArray=new string[static_cast<int>(m_frase.length())];
            string risultato="";
            for (int j=0; j<static_cast<int>(m_frase.length()); j++)
            {
                    cArray[j]=this->chr(j);
                    if (this->chr(j)==a)
                       cArray[j]=b;
                    risultato += cArray[j];
            }
            m_frase=risultato;  // the string is ok: don't touch!
    }
};



void main()
{
    typedef superString string;
    string prova="yellow";
    cout << prova.read();
    for (int I=0; I<prova.length(); I++)
         cout << prova.chr(I) << endl;
    cout << "\n" << prova.length() << endl;
    string successo=prova; // success! the class is automatically converted
                           // to string !
    cout << successo << endl;

    string profumo=prova.replace("y","b");  // *****
    cout << profumo << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You include `<string>`, you say `using namespace std;`, then you typedef your own string class to `string`, and somehow you expect this to work?

Comment: Please void `string* cArray = new string[..];`. You have a memory leak there because you never deleted the array using `delete[]`. It is usually not a good idea to be inheriting from `std::string` or any containers/classes that do not have a `virtual destructor`.

Comment: @juanchopanza. I believed the typefed experiment in this way was interesting, anyway if you could tell me the right way to go....

Comment: @alwaystudent Don't say `using namespace std`, and don't re-use names of standard library types (because there is this thing called argument dependent look-up, which allows you to use std lib names without pre-fixing them with `std::` under certain circumstances.

Comment: Standard Library classes are not dessigned to be extended through inheritance. Thats why they don't have a virtual dtor. So forget this kind of exercise. Is useless.

Comment: This code is wrong in so many ways, that the only thing I can say is: read a book on C++ and try again. Also please, learn to use English, and not Italian, as your language for names and comments.

Comment: Interesting way to combine inheritance and composition... /*end sarcasm*/

Answer (score 0):

... actually the Inheritance & typedef experiment works now.
What I wanted to see was if it is possible to write a class inherited from string and then use string in the code ( replacing the class name using typedef )
This is the version with inheritance & typedef ( perfectly working ):

```
// superString.cpp :  superString with inheritance & typedef

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class superString : public string
{
public:
    string m_frase;
    superString(string frase){ m_frase=frase; }
    operator string() { return m_frase; }
    int length() {return static_cast<int>(m_frase.length());}
    string chr(int posizione)
    {
        if (posizione < static_cast<int>(m_frase.length()))
        {
           string result(m_frase,posizione,1);
           return result;
        }
        else return "xx";
    }
    string read(){ return m_frase;}
    void replace_chr(string a, string b)
    {
        string *cArray=new string[static_cast<int>(m_frase.length())];
        string risultato="";
        for (int j=0; j<static_cast<int>(m_frase.length()); j++)
        {
           cArray[j]=this->chr(j);
           if (this->chr(j)==a)
                cArray[j]=b;
           risultato += cArray[j];
        }
        delete [] cArray;
        m_frase=risultato;  
    }
};


void main()
{
    typedef superString string;
    string prova="yellow";
    cout << prova.read() << endl;
    for (int I=0; I<prova.length(); I++)
        cout << prova.chr(I) << endl;
    cout << "\n" << prova.length() << endl;
    string successo=prova; // success ! the class automatically converts itself 
                          into string !
    cout << successo << "***" << endl;

    prova.replace_chr("y","b");  
    string fine=prova; 
    cout << fine << "***" << endl;
    cout << prova.read() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

The only problem left is that I write :

```
string successo=prova;
cout << successo << "***" << endl;
```

and this fails to work while the normal prova.read() works as in texbooks.
( I have some C++ books and that's why I attempt difficult exercises, I want to learn more :-)  )
In the normal class ( without inheritance ) the 2 lines above work perfectly.
In reality in textbooks I did not find something like string successo=prova to read a property of the class and prova.read() should be all that is needed but now I wonder why above fails and below works.
This is the normal class without Inheritance & typedef, those 2 lines do the job and print m_frase ( why above they do not ?):

```
// superString.cpp : superString without Inheritance and typedef
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

class superString 
{ 
private:
    string m_frase;
public:
    superString(string frase){ m_frase=frase; }
    operator string() { return m_frase; }
    int length() {return static_cast<int>(m_frase.length());}
    string chr(int posizione)
    {
        if (posizione < static_cast<int>(m_frase.length()))
        {
            string result(m_frase,posizione,1);
            return result;
        }
        else return "xx";
    }
    string read(){ return m_frase;}
    void replace_chr(string a, string b)
    {
        string *cArray=new string[static_cast<int>(m_frase.length())];
        string risultato="";
        for (int j=0; j<static_cast<int>(m_frase.length()); j++)
        {
            cArray[j]=this->chr(j);
            if (this->chr(j)==a)
                cArray[j]=b;
            risultato += cArray[j];
        }
        delete [] cArray;
        m_frase=risultato;  
    }
};



void main()
{
    superString prova="yellow";
    cout << prova.read() << endl;
    for (int I=0; I<prova.length(); I++)
            cout << prova.chr(I) << endl;
    cout << "\n" << prova.length() << endl;
    string successo=prova; // failure ! successo cannot be printed
    cout << successo << "***" << endl;

    prova.replace_chr("y","b");  
    string fine=prova;
    cout << fine << "***" << endl;  // failure ! fine cannot be printed !
    cout << prova.read() << endl; 

    system("pause");
}
```

I hope I have deleted/replaced all comments in italian. If you read something in Italian it is clear it is not for you to read. I apologize but I did not believe leaving those comments was a so big issue :-)
Can anyone give me a constructive comment about why in the latter version

```
string successo=prova;
cout << successo << "***" << endl;
```

prints the string and in the former it does not ? The same problem happens with the string fine, of course.